# Are there any type of displays that take no power to maintain their image?

Tags: display

Are there any type of displays that take no power to maintain their image? A display like this would keep it's previous state even after losing its power connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [electronic ink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_paper) displays used in devices like the Kindle do not require power to maintain the display only to change it.